# line break after certain number or characters or words

Tags: jquery, css, layout

Is there a way to wrap text (line break) after a certain word or number or letters? The use case is a long logo text.

The following css breaks the word in half, so not useful for me.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
```

`white-space: nowrap` is also not useful for me because I need to the line to break at some point.

Comment: `<wbr/>` perhaps?

Comment: What certain word or number or letters? Should it be an unconditional break or optional (i.e. applied if the text does not fit otherwise)? Please be specific. As asked, the question could probably be answered only “Yes”; the rest depends.

Comment: `white-space: prewrap` ? any example of text to show that do not wrap as you wish ?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking at certain number of characters is not possible through CSS. The below jQuery snippet does that.

```
var breakAt = 4; //breaks at 4 characters
var brokenString = $("#element").html();
brokenString = brokenString.substring(0, breakAt) + "<br>" + brokenString.substring(breakAt);
$("#element").html(brokenString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either put a content in a div and put display flex, flex-wrap, so it will wrap whatever content in its container.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src"logo">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

container{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width:200px
}
```